# Is there a faster way of assigning an image to lots of buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms Application that I need to assign an image to all 100 buttons, the problem is, that I need to do it randomly every time... Is there a faster way of doing this?

My first idea was to use the basic method of assigning that image to a variable and then assigning the image to the button:

```
Bitmap P_Farm = new Bitmap(@"IMAGE PATH.jpeg");

this.button1.Image = P_Farm;
```

But the problem with that is that I will need to do this for all 100 buttons.

```
this.button1.Image = P_Farm; // "P_Farm is just the path to the image"
this.button2.Image = P_Farm;
this.button3.Image = P_Farm;
this.button4.Image = P_Farm;
```

I want to keep my code as dry as possible.
The reason I can't just do it through the "Image" option in the "Properties" window is because eventually I will have a random image for every button on every load of the app. So first it will be

```
this.button1.Image = Z_Farm;
this.button2.Image = C_Farm;
this.button3.Image = P_Farm;
this.button4.Image = P_Farm;
```

then

```
this.button1.Image = P_Farm;
this.button2.Image = P_Farm;
this.button3.Image = Z_Farm;
this.button4.Image = Z_Farm;
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do something like reading every line in a text file but instead of the line changing with each try, the button changes

```
int i = 0;

while (true) // Something like this loop but changing not the line, but the button
{
    this.button[i].image = P_Farm; // this obviously doesn't work
    I++;
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense

Thanks a lot!

Comment: put all button in a List<Button> and all Images in an ImageList !

Comment: So lists are not only for strings, integers etc?

Comment: No. List<T> can hold any type and if you have a grid of buttons it will provide a neat way to enumerate them, ie use a loop to do things with them. Note tht you can also use the same Click handler for all and in its code cast sender to Button to access each one indivudually.. You can also access List<T> elements like you would an array.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. - Btw: You can also create all those buttons in code dynamically. Look around, many examples here..

Comment: I don't quite see the point of creating them dynamically when I can drag and drop them, resize and colour them all there and then, is there an advantage to using code over the drag and drop interface? EDIT- that's when the buttons will ALWAYS stay the same in the app, size and colour and position-wise

Comment: Well, anything done 100x is tedious work. A loop otoh is not only fast but also very dynamic. How would you go about when you want to change to different sizes or numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You can also loop through all the controls in your form, find the ones that are buttons and change their image that way. Of course you don't want to change them all. What I usually do is set a number to the `Tag` property:

```
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            if (control is Button theButton && (int)theButton.Tag == 5)
            {
                theButton.Image = P_Farm;
            }
        }
```

This will not work if you have panels with buttons that you want to change too. You will have to write a recursive function that involves all the possible containers in your form such as panels.
If you want to change all the buttons in a container like a panel you would only change your `foreach` line to something like `foreach (Control control in panel.Controls)`.

In the future, when you decide that not all buttons will have the same image, you could set an image based on the `tag` property like this:

```
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            if (control is Button theButton && (int)theButton.Tag >= 5)
            {
                switch ((int) theButton.Tag)
                {
                    case 100:
                        theButton.Image = P_Farm;
                        break;
                    case 101:
                        theButton.Image = Z_Farm;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Because we are assuming that all buttons have an `int` in their `tag` property, you should add a number to all buttons, including those that should not change like your Cancel and Ok buttons. Something like a zero to exclude them from the image assignement.

I'm sure that there are better ways. I haven't done WinForms in a while.